# modelsim: find processes/variables

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I would like to write a nice function that adds signals and process variables to the wave. While it's quite easy with signals, I don't know how to do it with variables. I would expect something like "find processes" and "find variables" in analogy to "find instances" and "find signals", but I haven't found anything like this in the manual. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I do two things:

1. Use modelsim log command.  If you type in log -r UUT/* it will log all signals, variables, etc associated with your UUT instantiation and all subcombonents.  I set up a script to call log -r /* every time I launch modelsim.
2. Use modelsim do files.  When running a particular simulation, I'm usually interested in a subset of the signals of the UUT, so I create a do file for just those signals.  Then every time I rerun that simulation I pass in the do file with the -do modelsim switch.

I'm not sure of a way to script modelsim in the way you're describing, but maybe the above suggestions will accomplish your goal.

Comment: What I would like to have is to be able to click somewhere in the device hierarchy and bring to the wave all the signals and variables in a quick and readable way - sort for inputs/outputs/internals, color them differently, put some dividers like "PROCESS BLA-BLA: VARIABLES" etc. It works with signals, but for variables I need to know the names of the processes in order to do "add wave proc_name/*". I can list the names of the instances easily with "find instances", but I'm looking for the way to list processes. It looks like there is no way for this.

Comment: The closest may be `find insource "process"`, but this only look at the source as text, so some amount of Tcl processing is required afterwards.  The missing find for process looks like an oversight.

Comment: `log -r` doesn't log variables (in my experience), only signals. I've logged variables explicitly via a process path.  (BTW, I'm not sure what 'etc.' as you wrote in your answer would apply to, what else were you thinking is logged?)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add option "-vhdlvariablelogging" to the vsim call. (modelsim.ini has a similar setting)

The WildcardFilter variable contains "Variable" by default. Try to remove Variable from this list (either in modelsim.ini or via "set" command). Maybe your function then works for variables as it does for signals.

Regards - Frank